# Apple Music free trial ending

Tags: ios, apple-music

As my free trial of Apple Music is due to end very soon, and I do not intend to pay for continued service, is there anything I should be doing before the trial ends to avoid any problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off auto-renewal. If you are on iOS:

1. Open the Music app
2. Tap the profile icon in the top left to get to the account menu
3. Choose **View Apple ID**
4. Under **Subscriptions > Manage**, turn off auto-renewal.

That's it.